# How to create a layout template using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, templates, jsp-tags

I am attempting to create a layout template to re-use in various JSP pages so certain common HTML (scripts, styles, meta tags, etc) don't have to be duplicated everywhere.

I am not very familiar with JSP but from what I can tell the way to do this is using tag files. What I have almost works but it appears that JSPs do not accept JSP/Java code within the body of a tag?

My template tag in `WEB-INF/tags/layouts/base.tag`:

```
<%@tag description="Base page layout" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@attribute name="title" fragment="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><jsp:invoke fragment="title" /></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <jsp:doBody />
  </body>
</html>
```

This is `some-page.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="layout" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/layouts" %>

<% String txt = "Some text..."; %>

<layout:base>
  <jsp:attribute name="title">Hello!</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>
    <h1><%= txt %></h1> 
  </jsp:body>
</layout:base>
```

The `<h1>` tag renders but the content from the variable does not. I have also tried using `<c:set var="txt" value="${txt}" />` and many other variations but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to make this work or another approach that I'm not seeing? I cannot find anything on the web that explains how to accomplish this.

This seems like a very simple and common thing to want to do with templates and from every templating language I've used in the JavaScript world, this is supported but I'm surprised this isn't easier in JSP.

Comment: Have you tried `sitemesh`?

Comment: @lucumt not at this point. Unless I'm missing something sitemesh still requires you to define an outer HTML structure so not sure it is the same. Plus it seems your content has to be in a specific location? I'm working on an app with thousands of JSPs so I can't just move everything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, try replacing `<jsp:doBody />` with `<%@include file="some-page.jsp" %>`

Where `some-page.jsp` is your JSP code to be inserted.

Comment: I want to be able to use a template in my JSP files, not include a file into another. This template would be used by hundreds of other files so I need to be able to place content into the body tag of this template for each page. Hope that makes it clearer what I'm trying to do

Comment: You example would only work with one page. I want to do this with any page. I want to define the parent template for a JSP page to use (eg `base.tag`)